# Why do my node packets sent using emit arrive in parts?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm currently trying to build an audio streaming system using a node.js server, for my purposes I want to be able to monitor some info on each packet as it is received by the client. To achieve this I am segmenting a WAV file into the header and a stream of segments which are sent via a socket.io emit, then received by the client using js io's .on.

The problem is that the client is receiving more packets than I sent, looking over the packets some of them are a single chunk split up between several packets. For example one of the files split up into 642 chunks each being sent with it's own emit, then the client is receiving 842 packets on .on.

Server side:

```
  for (var i = 44; i < fileSizeInBytes; i += inc) {
    var finalByte = i;
    finalByte += inc;

    var audio_stream = fs.createReadStream( track_location , { start: i, end: i + inc } );
    audio_stream.on( 'data', function(data){
      socket.emit('stream_audio', data);
    });
  };
```

Client side:

```
socket.on( 'stream_audio' , function( data ){ // on chunk recieved

    var segment = wavify(toArrayBuffer(data.data), numberOfChannels, sampleRate);
        context.decodeAudioData(segment, function(buf) {
            audioStack.push(buf);
        });

    console.log('Chunk read');
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Is there any way to stop the chunks from being split up? Or is there a way to rejoin them in the client?

I'm aware there is a limit to how much data can be sent at once, I am sending 20480 bytes at once, which is to my knowledge below that limit

Comment: absolutely  client receive more packets. so many reasons are there like some packets destroyed, some not have correct checksum, some packets sent to maintain stream  ............

Comment: TCP (what you essentially use) is a stream protocol and not a packet or message protocol. The OS kernel is free to merge or split anything before sending and similar merging of read packets on the client side might be done. If you need a message based protocol with TCP you need to add your own application layer on top of TCP.